# How to check for an unique user with jQuery Ajax in Struts 2?

Tags: java, ajax, jquery, struts2

I'm having any application in which I have `email_id` as unique and when the end user enters his `email_id` I have fired SQL query through Ajax which check whether this `email_id` exists or not. Until here it's working fine but now I what if that `email_id` exists then I want to display it on the JSP page like "This id is already taken" and vice-versa.

So my question is how to get the response from Struts app and give it to Ajax or JSP page and what to write in `struts.xml` result tag?

**This is my Ajax call to `EmailCheck.action`:**

```
$("#email").blur(function() {
      var EmailV = $("#email").val();
        if(EmailV.length > 10){
            $('#Loading').show();
            $.get("EmailCheck.action", {
                Email_Id: EmailV   
            }, function(response){
                $('#Info').fadeOut();
                $('#Loading').hide();
                setTimeout("finishAjax('Info', '"+escape(response)+"')", 450);
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**This is my `struts.xml`:**

Should there be result tag for this Email type checker?

```
 <action name="EmailCheck"  class="org.register.customers.EmailCheckAction" method="EmailCheck">
          <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
          <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
          <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

**This is my `Action` code:**

```
 public String EmailCheck() throws Exception{
         
     System.out.println(user.getEmail_Id());

       boolean create = Check_Email(user);

 //  "this is my sql call to check the existence of email"

    if (true) {       
       
        return "input";
    } else {          
        
        return ERROR;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Use [Struts2-json-plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call an Ajax action you can return a `dispatcher` result. In this case a rendered JSP fragment will output as a response. Also, you have options to return a `stream`, `json`, or `none` results. To your case I will consider the first option. First look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17133663/573032) answer to get you familiar how to return a `stream` result with `text/html` content type. Then in the JSP you should create a target div where you put the response.

```
<div id="result"/>
```

now modify your JS to insert result into div.

```
}, function(response){
  $("result").html(response);
```

Comment: hey Thanks for the reply but what should i write in struts.xml result type i.e is my strut.xml correct

Comment: Write `type="stream"` or `type="json"` or write nothing, read the answer and use first option, you didn't post `struts.xml`, so I can't see it.

Comment: I have posted my struts.xml the above 2 code is that one and thanks for your comment it worked and also will you specify the way to write struts.xml as it will help me further

Comment: This is your ultimate guide http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/configuration-elements.html

Comment: @ShoaibDoulatabad Just reminder, If it worked you can accept it as correct answer.