# How to get JSONArray values in Jquery Ajax url?

Tags: java, jquery, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-codebehind-plugin

I have JSONArray value in struts2 action class and need to pass to Jquery Ajax url to display into jquery datatable.

Action class:

```
public String JSONOarr(){
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    try {
        Iterator it = findList.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            SearchResult part = (SearchResult) it.next();
            ja.add(part.getlist1());
            ja.add(part.getlist2());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Struts2 codebehind annotation in class level:

```
@Result(name="success",type=JSONResult.class,value=""
```

Jquery for get the JSONArray:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : '<s:url action="part" method="list" />',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
```

How to get this JSONArray value ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265