# how to return json result in jquery function from action class

Tags: ajax, struts2

My aim is to display customer info by costumer id by calling my strus2 action change of selectbox value.

My problem is: what should i return from my action class to get the value in json format

I tried the following code, but i don't know what is wrong with it

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
  $(function()
   {    alert("This function is calling, on change event of selectbox and customer id="+$(this).val());
     $("#customersjsonlstid").change(function(e)
         { 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'showCustomerInfoById.action',  //action name
                        data: "customerid=" + $(this).val(),    
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {    

                            // Set the inputs from the json object , json output : {"price": "123.40", "distributor": "XYZ Inc."}          
                            $('#autocompleter_div_result1').val(data.distributor); //showing data on particular div
                            $('#autocompleter_div_result2').val(data.price);  //showing data on particular div
                        }
                    });
                });
    });             
</script>
```

Selectbox:

```
                            <sj:select 
                                id="customersjsonlstid" 
                                name="editionType" 
                                href="%{customerJsonselecturl}" 
                                list="lstcust"
                                listValue="name" 
                                listKey="id"   
                                autocomplete="false"
                            />     
             <div id="autocompleter_div_result">`
```

struts.xml

```
        <action name="showCustomerInfoById" class="v.esoft.actions.customerdetails.CustomerSelectAction" method="CustomerdetailsById">
             <result name="success" type="json"/> 
        </action>
```

Action class

```
    public class CustomerSelectAction extends ActionSupport {

     private String  customerid;


//---------------------------------------------------------
   public String CustomerdetailsById()
    {
        System.out.print("--------Method called, customer id-----------"+customerid);
        return customerid;
    }
     //---------------------------------------------------------


public String getCustomerid() {
    return customerid;
}


public void setCustomerid(String customerid) {
    this.customerid = customerid;
}

  }
```

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: @mohkhan problem was here ` url: 'showCustomerInfoById.action'` i removed the .action now function is calling.

Comment: @mohkhan i updated my question, please read it once more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265

Comment: Post the `struts.xml`.

Comment: @AndreaLigios  The above action is calling on selectbox change event, if i would like to call it for autocompleter jquery function, then how to do?                                                                            Please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104310/unable-to-get-id-from-the-struts2-auto-completer-on-change-event

Comment: @RomanC i want to call the above action on struts2 jquery autocompleter   how to do this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104310/unable-to-get-id-from-the-struts2-auto-completer-on-change-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<action name="showCustomerInfoById" 
        class="v.esoft.actions.customerdetails.CustomerSelectAction">
             <result name="success" type="json"/> 
</action>
```

Hint: removed attribute: method = "CustomerdetailsById"

```
@Override
public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

In this case, you will get a json object like this:

```
{
    "customerId":"value(customerId)"
}
```

You can also call showCustomerInfoById.action in your browser, you should see the json shows in the browser.

Comment: I have a new doubt, i would like to use struts2 jquery autocompleter instead of selectbox, then how i  will define my  jquery function?  Please update this also in your question

Comment: @Danny it is very easy, you are using `struts2-jquery-plugin`, just check out this example https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag

Comment: As you said, i followed your link, and implemented struts2 autocompleter in above example instead of `<sj:select`   But my problem is i am not getting id , when user is selecting option value from `<sj:autocomplter`  . It is giving `undefine` . I used this code        `$(function(){
    $.subscribe('selectEmployee', function(event,data) {
        var param = (event.originalEvent.id);  
      alert(param);
         });
  });`

Comment: @Danny it really hard to understand in this way, you may create a new question with this, wir should try to help you

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104310/unable-to-get-id-from-the-struts2-auto-completer-on-change-event

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and finally it got resolved.
you can try like this :

```js
$("#customersjsonlstid").change(function(e)
         { 
         var   customeridJson =    $('#customersjsonlstid').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'showCustomerInfoById',  //action name   same name in struts.xml
                        data: "customerid=" + customeridJson,    
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        success: function(data) {    

                            // Set the inputs from the json object , json output : {"price": "123.40", "distributor": "XYZ Inc."}          
                            $('#autocompleter_div_result1').val(data.distributor); //showing data on particular div
                            $('#autocompleter_div_result2').val(data.price);  //showing data on particular div
                        }
                    });
                });
    });
```

I did the same and it worked for me.
I hope this works for you as well.