# Struts 2 JSON Return back JSON array

Tags: json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

It seems that the Struts 2 JSON plugin returns back a object structure ({..ect..}) as the base value by default - Is there a way to configure the struts 2 json plugin such that it returns back an array object, like so?

```
[
    {
    "blah1": "1",
    "blah2": "2"
    },
    {
    "blah3": "3",
    "blah4": "4"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Use the root param in the xml config:

```
<result name="success" type="json">
        <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
        ....
        <param name="root">myArray</param>
</result>
```

Comment: Exactly, because JSON Plugin serializes the entire Action ;) Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265

Comment: content type "application/json" is a default, not necessary