# How to get data(JSONObject) returned from an action class in jsp using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am trying to get the Json Object data in JSP using Ajax.
I have action class where I am putting data in Json Object, and returning success, as shown below:

```
public String execute()
{  
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    System.out.println("here inside action-------------");
    PersistenceService svc = PersistenceServiceImpl.getInstance();
    status = svc.getStatusByFileId(fileId);
    System.out.println("status is "+status);
    numRecords = svc.getNumRecordsByFileId(fileId);
    System.out.println("num records are "+numRecords);
    obj.put("status", status);
    obj.put("records", numRecords);
    System.out.print("json data is "+obj);
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

My jsp ajax is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#refresh").click(function(){
        var fileId=id;
        alert("ajax id is "+fileId);
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'checkStatusAndNumRecs',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{fileId:fileId},
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert("data is :"+data); ->first alert
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(eval(data));
                alert("after parsing"); ->second alert
                $("#div1").html(obj.status);
                $("#div2").html(obj.records);
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                $("#div1").html("It was a failure !!!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my `struts.xml` for this ajax action:

```
<action name="checkStatusAndNumRecs" class="com.mxui.checkStatusAndNumRecsAction" method="execute">
    <result name="SUCCESS">statusnrecs.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Problem is some times its going to success and many times its going to error,
and `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(eval(data));`->this line is not executing when ever it goes for success, alert before this line is coming but after this line i have put alert that is not showing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096564/573032

Comment: [About Struts2-JSON Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265)

Answer (score 0):

The error is here

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(eval(data));
```

Use either

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); //probably better
```

or

```
var obj = eval(data); //older
```

not both. Also, you might to try

```
try {
  obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: thankyou i tried both var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); and var obj = eval(data);but second alert is not executing at all

Comment: is my action class method correct..where i am putting data in JSONObject

Comment: @Frisch, can you help me in this after using var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); i alerted data,there nothing in that ..

Comment: Sounds like you're not getting any reply with data; check that the url you're calling is correct. Maybe use fiddle2 or firebug? Also, I find console.log easier to use then alert.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to return json in struts,
you struts.xml must set result's type = json,like this:

```
    <action name="checkStatusAndNumRecs" class="com.mxui.checkStatusAndNumRecsAction" method="execute">
        <result name="SUCCESS" type="json"></result>
    </action>
```

Comment: thankyou i updated the struts,xml according to this then also same,second alert is not coming??

Comment: can you please tell me is the action class execute method i have posted is correct