# Reload a Div with content JSON Struts2 Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, json, html, struts2, reload

I need reload the content of a div with a part of an object JSON.
The code below does it perfectly, but the resulting div get all the JSON object and between `{}`. I need the content to appear only one variable.

**JSP:**

```
<s:url id="ajax1" value="ajax1.action"/>
<sj:div id="div1" 
    href="%{ajax1}" 
    reloadTopics="reloaddiv1">
</sj:div>
<sj:a 
    id="refreshlink" 
    onClickTopics="refreshdiv" 
    button="true">Refresh Div
</sj:a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.subscribe('refreshdiv', function(event,data) {
            $.publish('reloaddiv1');
        });
    </script>
```

**My action:**

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default" namespace="/">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
    </result-types>

    <action name="ajax1" class="action.Div">
        <result type="json"/>
    </action>

</package>
```

MY CLASS action.Div

```
String hi = "hi world";
String bye = "bye world";

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    return SUCCESS;
} 

/* getters and setters*/
```

Output shown in my div:

```
{"bye":"bye world","hi":"hi world"}
```

How do I make you see just `"hi world"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Struts2 JSON Plugin serializes the entire Action, so if you need only one variable, you need to specify a `root` object (`"hi"`, in your case) in struts.xml.

  Reading this answer could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265
- You will then get `"hi world"`. If you want the value without the double quotes, you need to instruct JQuery plugin to make it aware that it's dealing with JSON Data; add `dataType = "json"` to your `<sj:div>` as [described here](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DivTag), and you will get `hi world`.

Comment: tnx for your answer. That answer generated me some problems, I Have an Object "cliente" that replace to "Hi" and i have many Divs. In each div i load for example "cliente.name" in other div i load "cliente.surname" and all in the same page. What can i do? The problem is in: Load all objet cliente in each the div

Comment: I did not understand, that means I should ask another question in another post? or the same?

Comment: Ask another question expanding what you was saying in the comment. This is a legit question, and already has a correct answer; changing the question after it was answered won't help future visitors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144327/load-many-divs-from-a-grid-struts2-jquery-plugin

Comment: I try to explain as much as possible so that you achieve understand me, I hope you achieve read all and can help me, I searched for all the web and do not achieve. So help me plz.

Comment: Hi, I have reconsidered the question for you is easier to help. read it please

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167826/load-parts-of-a-json-in-many-divs-struts2

Comment: I asked a new question, if you would be so kind please come to visit my post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235676/json-ajax-struts2-render-json-in-html