# JSON + AJAX + STRUTS2 + RENDER JSON IN HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, struts2

I have a call ajax:

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.subscribe('cellselect', function(event, data) {
            var cell = event.originalEvent.cellcontent; 
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url  : "codcli.action?cliente.codcli="+cell,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(result){
                    if (result != null && result.length > 0){
                        $.publish('name');
                        $.publish('emails');
                    }
                },
                error : function(xhr, errmsg) {alert("No values found..!!");}
            });
        });
    </script>
```

***ACTION***

```
    <action name="codcli" class="intranet.ConsultarAlumno" method="CargarDatos">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="root">
                cliente
            </param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

That return the next String JSON

***JSON RESULT WITH FIREBUG (OBJECT "cliente")***

```
{"apemat":null,"apepat":null,"cicact":"01","clientedociden":null,"clienteemail":[{"emacli":"fabiolas_abada@unsm.pe"},{"emacli":"fabiolas_loved_11_44@hotmail.com"}],"clientesemestre":null,"clientetelefono":{"contel":0,"escuela":null,"facultad":null,"fechorusucre":null,"fechorusumod":null,"ideusucre":null,"ideusumod":null,"numtel":"   075 225476   975345737","tipotelefono":null},"codant":null,"codcli":"2012534852","codgraaca":null,"codpai":null,"codusu":null,"deuacumor":null,"deuacupen":null,"dirdom":"CALLE JIRON UNION 1274-LA VIRGEN","escuela":{"codesc":"02","desesc":"DERECHO","desescban":null,"desescres":null,"facultad":null,"fechorusucre":null,"fechorusumod":null,"ideusucre":null,"ideusumod":null,"nomdiresc":null,"proproesc":0,"staesc":null,"tipogrado":null},"estcar":null,"estciv":null,"exaadm":null,"facultad":{"codfac":"06","desfac":"DERECHO","desfacres":null,"dirfac":null,"fechorusucre":null,"fechorusumod":null,"ideusucre":null,"ideusumod":null,"nomrep":null,"proprofac":0,"stafac":null,"tipperaca":null,"ubigeo":null},"fechorusucre":null,"fechorusumod":null,"fecnac":null,"ideusucre":null,"ideusumod":null,"moding":null,"modtit":null,"nom":"FABIOLA  MARIA","nomcom":"ABADA MUYAGA","numcreacu":null,"numcuracu":null,"numresing":null,"propongen":null,"semegr":null,"semestre":"2","seming":"20131","sex":null,"stacli":null,"tipcli":null,"turmat":"M","ubigeo":{"codpos":null,"codubigeo":null,"depubigeo":"LA LIBERTAD, TRUJILLO, LA VIRGEN","disubigeo":null,"proubigeo":null},"ubigeo2":null,"ultsemact":null,"ultsemmat":null,"valvar":"19\/08\/2013","year":"2013"}
```

***JSP***

```
<p>Here The name</p>
<div id="name"> Atributte "nom" </div>

<p>Here The list of emails</p>
<div id="emails"> Atributte "clienteemail" </div>
```

***QUESTION***

What is the best way to work the JSON string to display on the HMTL page the attributes "nom"(name) and "clienteemail"(list of emails) of the JSON String?

Comment: The result of type "json" doesn't return a string. If you want return a string you should use a `stream` result. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096564/573032

Comment: I express bad to say that a JSON was String. I just tried to explain my situation. Tnx anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
....

success : function(cliente){
    if (result != null && result.length > 0){
        $("#name"  ).html(cliente.nom);
        $("#emails").html("");
        for (var i=0; i < cliente.clienteemail.length; i++) {
            $("#emails").append("<br/>" + cliente.clienteemail[i].emacli);
        }
    }
},

....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can not believe it took me one week to realize that I was looking for: .html (Json.atributo).

Comment: Glad that it helped. For the future, remember that this kind of madness has one and one mother only: wrong tags. This question is all about jquery, but `jquery` tag is missing from your question (and then, I guess, from your google searches too... or coupled with other not-releavant / misleading tags :)