# How to set and access value of Struts 2 action variables using Ajax calls

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am trying to make an Ajax call to a Struts 2 action method and then displaying the value of a variable in the action class. Even though the method is getting called, I am unable to see the value of the variable. The getters and setters of the variable are in place in the action class.

**My action method:**

```
public String testMethod(){
    //Set value of variable "myVariable"
}
```

**The Ajax method:**

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "testmethod",    //the declaration in struts.xml
    success: function(){
       //how to access value of myVariable here
}
});
```

in the success callback of the Ajax call in the JSP page, I am trying to access it via the `<s:property>` but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

In the `success` callback function you should pass the results via parameter, then use this parameter to assign the value of your variable. For example

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<s:url action="testmethod"/>',    //the declaration in struts.xml
    success: function(data){
       //how to access value of myVariable here
       var myVariable = data;
}
});
```

To return the `data` via Ajax call you could see
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096564/573032) answer.