# How to get an Input Stream from Result in display:table?

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, stream, struts2-jquery

I have an action, that ends with these lines:

```
String pageVisitJson = new Gson().toJson(pageVisitLogList);
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pageVisitJson.getBytes());
return SUCCESS;
```

And the result of this action is:

```
@Results({
    @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS , type="stream", params={"contentType", "text/html", "inputName", "is"}),
    @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="tiles", location="/pageVisitReport.tiles")
})
```

`pageVisitReport.tiles` is the page where i need to display the table using display tag. Now, how the input stream `is` can be accessed in display tag. Is my `@Result` incorrect or is there something else? the display table will further be processed by jQuery.

Whenever my action is called, it just display all the records on a simple page.

Comment: you can't map two results to the same result name

Comment: Ok, i was considering it too...and for question point of view, i put that line here, coz i need to send that input stream to pagevisitreport.tiles as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result name attribute should be unique per action configuration, so the action is able to return this result.

Using a `stream` result type requires to provide a getter for the stream introduced by the `inputName` parameter.

The content type returned is `text/html` so you need to parse this text via javascript. You can use `JSON.parse(data)`. The `data` will be available to you if you make an Ajax request to the server like `$.ajax()` by providing the URL mapped to the action. On the `success` function handler you will get the `data`.

For the difference and explanation how to use a `stream` result vs `json` result to return json string to the client javascript see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096564/573032) answer.