# Returning JSON Object from Struts2 Action Giving Empty Data

Tags: java, json, struts2

**In Action:**

```
//Declaration
    JSONObject jObj1 = null;

    public JSONObject getjObj1() {
            return jObj1;
   }
   public void setjObj1(JSONObject jObj1) {
            this.jObj1 = jObj1;
   }

 //In Action method   
String jsong="{\"cid\":232}";
jObj1 = new JSONObject(jsong);

return Action.SUCCESS
```

**Struts Cfg File** :

```
<action name="jsonAction" class="jsonAction" method="getJson">
            <result type="json" name="success">
                <param name="root">jObj1</param>                
            </result> 
        </action>
```

I am getting empty result when I see in JSP console

Where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: why you are not using JSON plugin provided by S2 ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX - issue returning JSON value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093862/jquery-ajax-issue-returning-json-value)

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating it :)

The [Struts2-JSON-Plugin will serialize in JSON your Action's objects for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265), so you don't need (and it's an error) to encode them by yourself.

Then, keeping your code and config as it is, just change the Action to:

```
//Declaration
Map<String,Integer> jObj1 = null;

/* Getter and Setter */

//In Action method   
jObj1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
jObj1.put("cid",232);
return Action.SUCCESS
```

Comment: @Ligios , thanks for replying.. the actual scenario is..am getting json from the webservice as String(DTO objects List) i want to return it to the jsp .. how come i do that..

Comment: Use json interceptor and stream result, it's in the link on my answer, in Roman C's answer