# Struts 2 action response on jsp

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2, action

I would like to get a HTTPServletResponse of an Action on a jsp page, but i don't know how...

My ajax call on the jsp:

```
jQuery.ajax({
url : 'actionURL',
type: "POST",
data : {input: "example"},
dataType: "html",
success: function(response) {
alert(response);
if (response == 1) {
jQuery("#message").html("done!");
}
}
});
```

My Action class:

```
public class MyAction implements ServletResponseAware {

public final String execute() throws IOException {

        String return_code = "1";

        try {

            something...

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return_code = "0";
        }

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(return_code);

        return "success";
    }
}
```

How can i access only the return_code variable on jsp? Because now in the script alerts the whole page HTML code as response... Thanks!

Comment: Use `struts2-json-plugin` to return JSON response.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your variable **must** be at class-level, with a Getter;
2. It *should* be camelCase (`returnCode` instead of `return_code`), and potentially an Integer since it's containing a number;
3. Don't write anything in the response, Struts will do it for you; this is an action, not a servlet;
4. Never swallow exceptions;

   ```
   public class MyAction implements ServletResponseAware {

       private Integer returnCode;

       public Integer getReturnCode(){
           return returnCode;
       }

       public final String execute() throws IOException {    
           try {
               /* do something... */
               returnCode = 1;
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               returnCode = 0;
           }    
           return "success";
       }
   }
   ```
5. In struts.xml, map your `"success"` result to a JSP containing only the printed out value:

   ```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="struts-tags.tld"%>    
   <s:property value="returnCode" />
   ```

   Then the returned JSP will be a single value. But this is bad practice, and can easily lead to mistakes (extra whitespaces, for example). Then change your approach and...
6. Use [Struts2 JSON plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265) setting `returnCode` as `root` object (remember to change your `dataType` from `html` to `json`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry, this was only a snippet from my code...I modified my ajax script to this:
...dataType: "json",...
And the struts.xml:
<action name="myAction" class="xx.yy.portal.action.myAction">
         <result name="success" type="json">
          <param name="root">returnCode</param>
         </result>
        </action>
But now it throws Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: application/json;charset=UTF-8 not valid compared to [text/html]

Comment: Please add this code and the full exception stacktrace to your question, so we'll be able to help you. BTW, it's good that you've gone the JSON way.