# Populating Dropdown inside javascript from database through struts2 action class (using jtable)

Tags: ajax, database, drop-down-menu, struts2, jtable

Your site had helped me a lot in java web development. My only hindrance is Populating Dropdown inside javascript through `struts2` action class (using jtable). I have used your sample code "`AJAX based CRUD operation in Struts 2 using jTable plugin"`.

In below code snippet i want Department to be dropdown which gets value from database using l`ist2` method of `com.action.JtableAction` class.

**userDefinedJtable.js:**

```
 department : {
            title : 'Department',
            width : '30%',
            edit : true,
                            options : '/WebApplication1/list2Action',
                            list: false
        },
```

`list2` method inside JtableAction

```
public String list2() {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      obj.put("name", "foo");
      obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
      obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
      obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));

      return obj.toString();    
    }
```

Declaration in struts.xml

```
<action name="getJSONResult" class="com.action.JtableAction" method="list2">
            <result type="json" />
</action>
```

But when i accessed

```
 /WebApplication1/list2Action
```

i am getting this error

> HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action com.action.JtableAction
>   and result {"balance":1000.21,"num":100,"is_vip":true,"name":"foo"}

Kindly help me whether i am doing right thing or not. 
And what is required.

**EDIT**

struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="json-default">
        <action name="*Action" class="com.action.JtableAction" method="{1}">
            <result type="json">/jTable.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="getJSONResult" class="com.action.JtableAction" method="list">
            <result type="json" />
        </action>
        <action name="getJSONResult" class="com.action.JtableAction" method="list2">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="root">obj</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax - issue returning JSON value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093862/jquery-ajax-issue-returning-json-value)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Struts2-JSON-plugin,

1. Make your object private at class level, providing a getter for it:

   ```java
   private JSONObject obj;
   public getJSONObject() { 
       return obj; 
   }
   ```
2. Change your return type to SUCCESS:

   ```java
   public String list2() {
     obj = new JSONObject();

     obj.put("name", "foo");
     obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
     obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
     obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));

     return SUCCESS;
   }
   ```
3. Add a `root` object parameter to your result definition :

   ```xml
   <action name="getJSONResult" class="com.action.JtableAction" method="list2">
       <result type="json">
           <param name="root">obj</param>
       </result>
   </action>
   ```

Read more about how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265).

**EDIT**

You have at least two big errors in your struts.xml

1. If you are returning a result of type JSON, you can't return a JSP; remove JSON from your first result.
2. You can't name two action aliases with the same name in the same package: differentiate the names to make it work.

Fixed code:

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="json-default">
        <action name="*Action" class="com.action.JtableAction" method="{1}">
            <result>/jTable.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="getJSONResult1" class="com.action.JtableAction" method="list">
            <result type="json" />
        </action>
        <action name="getJSONResult2" class="com.action.JtableAction" method="list2">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="root">obj</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Obviously you need to change the name of the `getJSONResult` call adding 1 or 2 at the end.

P.S: Consider using different action classes, to get smaller actions and more granularity.

Comment: I have tried the steps you have provided. Thanks for your help. But when I have submitted [link] (http://localhost:9090/WebApplication1/list2Action) I got following {"JSONObject":{},"department":null,"emailId":null,"message":null,"name":null,"record":null,"records":null,"result":"OK","studentId":0}

Comment: @user3756876 are you using struts2-json-plugin ? Is your `<package>` extending `json-default` ? Is `JSONOBject` a JavaBean created by yourself ? P.S: It should be List2.action, with the dot

Comment: my struts.xml   'code'<struts>
   
 <package name="default" extends="json-default">
  <action name="*Action" class="com.action.JtableAction"
   method="{1}">
   <result type="json">/jTable.jsp</result>  
  </action>
                <action name="getJSONResult" class="com.action.JtableAction" method="list">
   <result type="json" />
  </action>
        <action name="getJSONResult" class="com.action.JtableAction" method="list2">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="root">obj</param>
    </result>
</action>
 </package>
       
</struts>

Comment: Next time edit your own question instead of posting code in comments. BTW your struts.xml is completely wrong