# Unable to send back array of in struts2 json plugin

Tags: java, arrays, json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I am using json plugin to handle json request and response in struts2. I want to send an array data in response in form of json but i am unable to do. At FE I always get an empty array. below is my Action class, struts.xml and response.

**TestAction:**

```
public class TestAction {

private String[] sArray = {"1","2"};
private int[] iArray = {1,2};
private String value = "value";

//getter setter
public String[] getSArray() {
    return sArray;
}
public int[] getIArray() {
    return iArray;
}
public String execute() {
return "success";    
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
<package name="name" namespace="/" extends="default,json-default">
       <action name="Test" 
            class="com.actions.TestAction">
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
                <param name="includeProperties">sArray,iArray,value</param>
            </result>
        </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

At Front End I get the following response

```
{"sArray":[],"iArray":[],"value":"value"}
```

Comment: `extends="default` should be `extends="struts-default`, not mandatory (since `json-default` already extends `struts-default`) and not cause of the problem, though.

Comment: thanks for info. I change the param to this
<param name="root">sArray</param>
and it work I get the value of sArray

Comment: And it worked ? Does it work if 1) you put the initialization in the execute() method, or 2) if you change from Array to List, or 3) if you remove exclude and includeproperties ? It should work, we're missing something basic :) Are you SURE your getters and setters are all there and all good ?

Comment: Yeah no problem with Getter Setter. I follow different tutorial and there is no special thing that need to do if we want to send an array. also If i use above way the response is little different. I got response this ["1","2"] where as it should be {"sArray":["1","2"]}

Comment: Of course, mine suggestions were shots in the dark, because appearently it should work as is, and your `root` attempt works like that because instead of the whole action, it is serializing only the root object, exactly as requested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265

Comment: I have added the getter method above. I also do some changes, I created a list of string and add a value in execute() function but in response I get empty list. I also initialize the iArray with null due to which in response I don't get iArray.

Comment: What can be the problem? Is there something necessary to do for parsing list or arrays? like adding some special interceptor?

Comment: One more thing in my application I am using CORS and I have to add some headers in the response to work on CORS.

Comment: Uhm... can you try the above code in a standalone page, not influenced by this CORS response changes ?

Comment: Yeah I try It but same problem. I get an empty array.

Comment: One other thing I am using struts2-core-2.2.1.jar library

Comment: All the versions (struts-core, struts-json, and so on) must match. Also I **strongly** suggest you to upgrade all of them to latest version, or at least to 2.3.15.3, to avoid dangerous security problems

Comment: I can't update the struts2-core but I can update the struts2-json plugin

Comment: I update the struts2-json-plugin but issue still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't name your object fields with single lower case letter (e.g. `sArray`). Change names to something different (e.g. `strArray`). In this way you don't need to guess what getters/setters names should be.

Second, the correct syntax for the `includeProperties` attribute of `struts2-json-plugin` for arrays is `^array\[\d+\]`.

So if your fields are `strArray` and `intArray` the configuration should be something like that:

```xml
<package name="name" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
  <action name="Test" 
      class="com.actions.TestAction">
    <result name="success" type="json">
      <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
      <param name="includeProperties">^strArray\[\d+\],^intArray\[\d+\],value</param>
    </result>
  </action>
</package>
```