# Autocomplete a textbox using sj:autocompleter with a dynamic list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, struts2, autocomplete, struts2-jquery

I am intending to display a list of suggestions for a textbox using `sj:autocompleter`.  When I hard code the data in the jsp it works fine.

```
<sj:autocompleter name="fruitNames" 
                  list="{'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'apricot'}" 
                  label="Fruit Names">
</sj:autocompleter>
```

But I want to get the list of suggestions dynamically from the action class. I tried doing this but it is not getting the values.

```
<sj:autocompleter name="fruitNames" list="fruitslist"
     label="Fruit Names">
</sj:autocompleter>
```

In my action class,

```
public String execute() {
    fruitslist= new ArrayList<String>();
    fruitslist.add("Apple");
    fruitslist.add("Banana");
    fruitslist.add("Orange");
    fruitslist.add("Apricot");
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have a getter:

```
    public List<String> getFruitslist() {
        return fruitslist;
    }
```

Since you posted your struts.xml and now it's clear that you want to use JSON, the code must be changed. The previous answer was referring to a standard Array from the main Action; in case of a JSON action, you need to specify an url in `href` attribute of the autocompleter to point to the separate JSON Action:

```
    <s:url var="remoteurl" action="ajaxAction"/>
    <sj:autocompleter
        id="fruitslist"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        delay="50"
        loadMinimumCount="2"
    />
```

Then you need to set your result as JSON, and your `root` object to your Array, like this:

```
    <action name="ajaxAction" class="org.struts.action.AjaxJsonAction"> 
        <result name="success" type="json">
            <param name="root">
                fruitslist
            </param>
        </result> 
    </action>
```

I strongly suggest you to read [how the Struts2-JSON plugin works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265).

Comment: I tried doing this but still doesn't work. I don't know if I am missing something. Is there any other configuration you need to do in the struts.xml.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
 <package name="default" extends="json-default">
   <action name="ajaxAction" class="org.struts.action.AjaxJsonAction">
        <result name="success">textboxAjax.jsp</result>
   </action>
</package>
</struts>

Comment: Sorry the formatting is lost when I pasted the contents of the file.

Comment: Answer edited. Please, when you need to add code, edit your question instead of posting it into comments

Comment: Thanks Andrea. That worked. Also, thanks for providing the link for a deeper explanation to Struts2-JSON.

Comment: Any reason to use array instead of list?

Comment: In the above example, if I do not want to use JSON how do I simply display the fruitslist in the web page? For example, if the criteria is "tropical", in my action class I need to query the database and return the list of tropical fruits to a different textbox in the jsp. One textbox to enter the criteria and the second to autocomplete based on the criteria entered in the first textbox. I don't have to use JSON to accomplish this. Correct?

Comment: Use an autocompleter. With json :)