# Autocomplete in strust2 on load page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2, autocomplete

I am not able to autofill autocomplete on load page.

Autocomplete work fine when call using direct action like

```
localhost:7070/StrutsDropDown/OtherBill.Action
```

But i want to call it on load page using ajax or using jquery.

Following things I have done.

My autocomplete is:

```
<s:label name="stateName" value="CustID:" /><s:autocompleter theme="simple" list="CustID" name="Cust_id"/>
```

My Action is:

```
private List CustID;
  public String execute(){
  CustID = new ArrayList();
  CustID.add("Alabama");
  CustID.add("Alaska");
  CustID.add("Arizona");
  CustID.add("Arkansas");
return SUCCESS;
}
```

So,How to fill autocomplete using ajax or jquery on

```
$(document).ready(function() {}
```

please somebody help me how to do it.

Comment: After return success you are redirecting from action to jsp page which have autocompleter right...???

Comment: But how to make call to action using ajax/jquery

Comment: I have edited the code...Did you try this...??

Comment: @Alone are you using the struts2-dojo plugin, asking about jQuery ? The correct way to use the <sj:autocompleter> from the struts2 jQuery plugin is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26518988/1654265

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called `<s:url>` tag through which u can trigger Action class....

In your Jsp page...

```
<s:url value="/OtherBill.Action" var="BillUrl" />
<s:a  href="%{BillUrl}">
  <button value="Check Bill Action" id="TriggerBillUrl"></button>
</s:a>
```

And your Jquery...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
alert("Inside the document ready");
$('#TriggerBillUrl').trigger('click');
});
```

Hope yout got it..:) :)

Comment: A button inside link? Trigger to click on button on page load to do what?

Comment: :P he just wanted to trigger Action class on page load...:) and to get Autocompleter