# Struts 2 autocomplete onchange event

Tags: javascript, struts2, autocomplete, struts-validation

I am using *struts2* autocompleter *dojo* tag and need to fire a *javascript* event onchange.

I have 2 questions.

1) How to fire onchange

2) dojo tags are not supported anymore. So what is the alternative?

Comment: Use Struts2-jQuery plugin's autocompleter [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26518988/1654265)

Comment: so dojo is out and jQuery is in and I should use jQuery for the said purpose. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Take a look at [the showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using **Struts2-jQuery plugin**'s you can achieve it as below :

Please check out select part where i am calling javascript function(`subinfo()`) as per your need.

```
(function( $ ) {
        var calltheData=false;
        $.widget( "ui.combobox", {

            _create: function() {
                var self = this,
                    select = this.element.hide(),
                    selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
                var input = this.input = $( "<input>" )
                    .insertAfter( select )
                    .val( value )
                    .autocomplete({
                        delay: 0,
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function( request, response ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                            response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                                var text = $( this ).text();
                                if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                    return {
                                        label: text.replace(
                                            new RegExp(
                                                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                            ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                        value: text,
                                        option: this
                                    };
                            }) );
                        },
                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            //jQueryOnchangeAutocompleter();
                            subinfo();

                            self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
                        change: function( event, ui ) {
                            if ( !ui.item ) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                    valid = false;
                                select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                    if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                if ( !valid ) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    $( this ).val( "" );
                                    select.val( "" );
                                    input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    })

                    .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

                input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                    return $( "<li></li>" )
                        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                        .appendTo( ul );
                };

                this.button = $( "<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>" )
                    .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                    .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                    .insertAfter( input )
                    .button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text: false
                    })
                    .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                    .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" )
                    .click(function() {
                        // close if already visible
                        if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                            input.autocomplete( "close" );
                            return;
                        }

                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                        input.focus();
                    });
            },

            destroy: function() {
                this.input.remove();
                this.button.remove();
                this.element.show();
                $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
            }
        });
    })( jQuery );



$( "#yourid" ).combobox();
```

You can write onchange as below:

```
 <s:select list="yourdatlist" name="yourid"
                id="yourid" listKey="wid" listValue="desc"
                headerKey="-1" headerValue="" theme="simple" onchange="subinfo();">
</s:select>
```