# How to pass JSON array from Struts 2 action class to jQuery?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, struts2

I creating a Java web application with an action file which generates data from database to a JSON array. Now, I want this JSON array to be passed to jQuery? How is that possible?

FYI. I applied Struts 2, Spring and Hibernate frameworks. I am not using PHP for this app.

Update:

This is my Struts 2 action method:

```
public static String jsonData = null;

public String generateJson() throws Exception
{
    JSONObject json = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    this.records = this.recordManager.getAllRecords();

    for (RecordEntity record : records)
    {
        json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("id", record.getId());
        json.put("firstname", record.getFirstName());
        json.put("lastname", record.getLastName());
        json.put("due", record.getDue());
        json.put("email", record.getEmail());
        json.put("website", record.getWebsite());
        jsonArray.put(json);
    }

    System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());

    jsonData = jsonArray.toString(); // jsonData will be passed to jQuery
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

And this is my jQuery. I am using BootstrapTable so this is the structure, and I want the value of jsonData to be passed to this jQuery:

```
$('#record').bootstrapTable({
    method : 'get',
    data: jQuery.parseJSON(VALUE_OF_jsonData_HERE),
    cache : ...
    ...
    ...
});
```

Comment: Provided the servlet prints the JSON-encoded data in the response output, all you have to do is fetch it through a regular ajax request, e.g. [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: How? Sorry I did not mention, I am new to servlets and Struts 2.

Comment: can also output the json into a javascript variable directly in the page. Approach is somewhat dependent on how it is used

Comment: You would get higher quality/more specific answers if you update the question to include the java code you have so far. `=]`

Comment: Hi Fabricio, question has been modified and codes have been added.

Comment: Use json plugin to generate json.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. Use Json plugin [like showed in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Ajax** will help you,

refer [this](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery/spring-framework-jquery-ajax-request-and-json-response-example) to get started, also do read about `Ajax` first to have a background

Comment: Yes, I already used that. Please note I have modified the question and added the codes. :)