# How to get a simple String from Action to JSP with Struts?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have this problem: I need to get some simple data from Action and send back to JSP (already loaded), so I have to manage the action to recover that data with jQuery `$.ajax` method. So here is my code:

**MyAction.java**

```
private String employee;
private InputStream inputStreamEmployee;
//these with getter/setter

public String someData() throws Exception{
        employee= "John Doe";
        inputStreamEmployee = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                  employee.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 

        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="getSomeData" method="someData" class="MyAction">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStreamEmployee</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

**data.js**

```
function getData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getSomeData',
        dataType: 'text',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('no data!!');
        }
    });
```

I checked this [resource](http://struts.apache.org/docs/how-can-we-return-a-text-string-as-the-response.html), but I need the javascript part. So I debugged and checked the development. The javascript method calls the action in java, and action returns `success`, but the `data` in `function(data)` doesn't get the InputStream correctly, it just get the whole html webpage source, as shown in the image:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I tried with some questions here, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093862/issue-returning-json-value and, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221528/return-a-string-from-struts2-action-to-jquery, but with no solutions.

Comment: What's the content of the HTML? Why are you setting the contentType to HTML if you don't want to return HTML? Why not use the JSON plugin?

Comment: The results are explicitly mapped via annotations but you have probably wrong action mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the javascript calls, your problem is that the request `www.yourdomain.com/getSomeData` is not returning a page with the text `John Doe`.

Why are you using an inputStream? If you are using JSP as templating system a simple solution would be

### MyAction.java

```
private String employee;

public String someData() throws Exception{
    employee= "John Doe";
    return "SUCCESS";
}


public String getEmployee(){
    return employee;
}
```

### stuts.xml

```
<action name="getSomeData" method="someData" class="MyAction">
    <result>/WEB-INF/.../templates/some_data.jsp</result>
</action>
```

### some_data.jsp

```
<%= employee%>
```