# struts2 ajax call response always shows null

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am trying to call the struts2 action class from my jsp using ajax. I can hit the action class and able to pass the parameters to action class. But the response that comes from action class to my ajax request is always null

All setters and getters are set correctly and they are working fine when I see in debug sysouts

## Action Class

```
@Override
@Action(value = "/search",
          results = { @Result(name = "success", type="json")})
public String execute() throws ParseException
{


    this.setName(this.term+": "+this.pos);
    System.out.println("Name: "+Name);

    JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(Name);


    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
}
```

## jsp

```
function Search()
{
    var term = document.getElementById("term").value;
    var pos = document.getElementById("pos").value;
    var itr = document.getElementById("itr").value;
    var pri = document.getElementById("pri").value;
    var atb = document.getElementById("atb").value;
    var jsonData = {};

    jsonData.term = term;
    jsonData.pos = pos;
    jsonData.itr = itr;
    jsonData.pri = pri;
    jsonData.atb = atb;

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "search",
         dataType: "json",
         data: jsonData,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(""+response);
            alert('Name: '+response.Name);
            //alert('Length: '+data[0].length);

          /*  $.each(data[0],function(index, value){
                alert("value " +value);
               });*/
            },
     error:  function(response){
         alert(response);
         alert(response.length);

         $.each(response,function(index, value){
            alert("value " + value);
            });
     }

     });

}
```

I can see the response always as null. I am not sure what is going wrong, but seems the coding part is correct. Am I doing some mistake in ajax call?

Comment: Control is coming to error function or success function?

Comment: Have you tried returning null from `execute()`?

Comment: @Mihir: Control is coming to Success function only

Comment: @Rahul: Yes I tried returning null from action , sill I can see the response as null only

Comment: @SrinivasRaju Success is not a function but a result code that is used to execute some result in the action configuration means success. that is this result is responsible for initializing a response and send it through http connection.

Comment: Unrelated, but I recommend following standard Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

1. As clearly explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265), you need to use the JSON plugin, that will serialize the entire action (or a single root object when needed). You don't need then to do the parsing yourself, just evaluate the `name` variable.
2. To send JSON from JSP to action instead you need to use the JSON Interceptor in your stack.
3. Ensure you have getters and setters for everything.
4. Your `Name` variable should be `name`, both in Java and in Javascript. Only the accessors / mutators should use the capitalized N (`getName`, `setName`).
5. If the error persists, check carefully console and logfiles for errors, with `devMode` set to true.
6. Since this comment has gone too far, I've turned it into an answer :)