# How To return only array not json object in struts2

Tags: java, json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin, struts-action

```xml
<action name="commissioner_info" method="commissioner_info" class="foo.bar.AdminInfoAction">
    <result name="json" type="json">    
        <param name="includeProperties">
            commissioner_info\[\d+\]\.fname,
            commissioner_info\[\d+\]\.designation,        
            commissioner_info\[\d+\]\.pathlocation
        </param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Above code giving Result:

```
{"commissioner_info":[{"designation":"IG1","fname":"BS  Bassi ","pathlocation":"http:\/\/103.231.125.106\/nesos\/imagerepresentatives\/151021104556Bhim.jpg"}]}
```

But I want only array not json object,like

```
[{"designation":"IG1","fname":"BS  Bassi ","pathlocation":"http:\/\/103.231.125.106\/nesos\/imagerepresentatives\/151021104556Bhim.jpg"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the object you want to be serialized as **[the root object](https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html#JSONPlugin-RootObject)**:

```xml
<result name="json" type="json">    
    <param name="root">
        commissioner_info
    </param>
</result>
```

Otherwise the whole action will be serialized. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265).