# how can we pass Struts2 action class to angularjs $http get

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

My goal is to display values as a list from a table to the model pop-up on the JSP page.

**action**

```
public class IcdAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<Icd10> icdCodes;

    public String execute() throws MalformedURLException, JsonProcessingException {
        SomeProcess ap = new SomeProcess();
        icdCodes = ap.getList();
        return SUCCESS;     
    }
}
```

**js**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('IcdCodesAction')
    .success(function(response){
         $scope.icdcodes = response;
    });
});
```

**struts.xml**

```xml
<action name="IcdCodesAction" class="com.emr.action.IcdAction" >    
    <result type="json">
    </result>
</action>
```

In the JSP file I am using `ng-repeat`on the `icdcodes`.

I am new to AngularJS. I am not able to figure out where is the issue which is preventing the list to be displayed.

If I use hardcoded json data for `$scopes.icdcodes`, then it is working fine.

Comment: Open devtools and check what server responds with.

Comment: Check if your method is being called, if it is then print the response and see what is inside.

Comment: Ugh, ICD10. Some hilarious codes, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `json` result is processed by the *struts2-json-plugin*, that [serializes the whole Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265).

Then you can:

1. read only the desired object from the serialized action:

   ```
   $http.get('IcdCodesAction')
   .success(function(response){
        console.log("this is the serialzied action -> " + response);
        console.log("this is what I want:  " + response.icdCodes);
        $scope.icdcodes = response.icdCodes;
   });
   ```

   **OR**
2. use the `root` attribute of the `json` result to specify the single element to serialize:

   ```xml
   <action name="IcdCodesAction" class="com.emr.action.IcdAction" >    
       <result type="json">
           <param name="root">icdCodes</param>
       </result>
   </action>
   ```

Comment: this is the serialzied action -> [object Object]
icdcodeangular.js:9 this is what I want:  undefined, this is what I am getting on console. Am I missing something in the action class?

Comment: Can you run the $http.get from the devTools console of your browser and open the [object Object] that is returned ? What's inside ?

Comment: [{"addedBy":null,"addedOn":null,"code":"a0","deleted":null,"description":"first icd"}]

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I modified last line to $scope.icdcodes = response; its working as I wanted to.

Comment: So you've used the root object. I guess you've used BOTH the approaches, while you should use the first **OR** the second. Glad that helped btw