# Struts 2 json result and xss hack

Tags: json, struts2, xss

Please consider this sample action which checks user upload file and returns a json of errors if there are any thing wrong to user.

The text in the jsp:

`Your file has this text which is not correct : I are a programmer`

```
public class SampleAction{

    private List<String> errorCodesForFileUpload = new ArrayList<String>();

   @Action(value = "sample-upload", 
        results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "json" .... }

         public String upload() {             
        
         // proccess user file and show incorrect lines to user
         errorCodesForFileUpload.add("Your file has this text which is not correct:" + USER_TEXT_IN_THE_FILE  );    
        }
```

}

In the jsp we parse and show the `errorCodesForFileUpload` . This has the XSS vulnerability (If the file has any javascript in it)

I can fix it by escaping user text, before adding it to `errorCodesForFileUpload`.

But there are many actions which has been developed like this.

Is there any better way to customize json result and escape every string, before write?

Comment: There are multiple approaches; a generic action with a `PreResultListener` that escapes some/all action parameters may be the easiest, or a response wrapper. It’s difficult to say what’s best/easiest w/o insight into the app, though.

Comment: I don't know if it's better to extend/customize the `json` result but there's a lot of different approaches to affect the JSON returned by the result. One of them I explored in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35753928/573032) question. Then you just need to override the `json` result type, or remove JSON plugin at all.