# simple ajax return json with exception in struts2 and Restful

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest, struts2

I have an action that should return a JSON from an AJAX call, but it throws an exception instead.

Do you have any clue on what could be the cause of the problem ?

Here is my code:

```
@Results({
    @Result(name="json", type="json", params = {"root", "json"})
})

public class TestController{

    public String tableData() {
        String test = "{'winston':'testing'}";
        JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(test);
        return "json";
    }
}
```

The exception thrown:

```
ERROR RestActionInvocation Exception processing the result.
net.sf.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.defaultBeanProcessing(JSONObject.java:818)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:699)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:172)
at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:274)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2655)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2721)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2736)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1424)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.defaultBeanProcessing(JSONObject.java:765)
```

Comment: object should be a bean not just a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. The Struts2 [`json` result will serialize a Java object into a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265) on its own, hence 
   you **do NOT** have to serialize it yourself;
2. The property must be accessible from outside, hence you can NOT define it *inside* the action method, but you need to do it at action level. Only non-transient, class-level properties with a getter will be serialized (even with the `root` attribute).

The code you want is:

```
@Results({
    @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, 
            type = "json", 
          params = {"root", "myJsonObject"})
})
public class TestController extends ActionSupport {

    private String myJsonObject;
    public String getMyJsonObject(){ 
        return myJsonObject; 
    }

    public String execute() {
        myJsonObject = "someValue";
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

After making it work with a String, `myJsonObject` can then be turned into a Map, or into a Bean (for example a bean with a `winston` property to which assign a `testing` value, in order to return the

> `{"winston":"testing"}`

JSON as in the example.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for your answer, but it seems not working in struts2.5.8, I am using the code same to you and working in struts2.3, but after I upgrade to 2.5.8, it have this exception. Do you know what happen? Thanks again~

Comment: Do I need to includes some new lib?

Comment: 2.5.8 is not the latest, try 2.5.10. BTW, if root is an object, does it implement Serializable ?

Comment: yes, i have upgrade to 2.5.10, the root is an object, it still can't serializable.
But I found i can use getModel with an correct object and it will override the json and return the correct json for me.

Comment: I don't see any model driven stuff in the question; if you post a different code, helping you will be a lot more difficult ;)

Comment: Andrea, I have solved the problem using model driven after i post this code, and i can get the correct json now, thanks for you help, i am very appreciate.=)