# Getting data from ActionClass to JSP in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2

I'm currently working on a school project which consists of developing a game using Struts2/JSP.

The problem I have is I can't get Data from my ActionClass to my JSP using jQuery.
It works great the other way and I found multiple sources to do so.

**Here is my minimized `GameAction.class`:**

```
private String playerColor;
private Map<String,Object> applicationMap;

public String execute (){

playerColor = ((Joueur)applicationMap.get("joueur")).getPlayerColor();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

NOTE: everything has a getter/setter.

**`game.js` :**

```
var $playerColor;
$(window).on('load', function () {

$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "gotoGameAction",
    data : "playerColor=",
    success : function (data) {
    $playerColor = data;
    var html = "<h2>" + $playerColor.toString() + "</h2>";
    $("#playerColor").html(html);
  }

})

});
```

**`Struts.xml`:**

```
<package name="default" extends="json-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="gotoGameAction" class="actions.logins.GameAction">
        <result name="success" type="json">/WEB-INF/views/game.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

This output I have on my JSP is : `[object Object]`.

I really can't get what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

I found some of mistakes in your code. It may helpful to you.

In **struts.xml**

Its

```
<result name="success" type="json">playerColor</result>
```

instead

```
<result name="success" type="json">/WEB-INF/views/game.jsp</result>
```

Here type `json` so variable to be passed.

And `playerColor` should have getter method in `GameAction`.

In Ajax call simply

```
success : function (data) {
    $("#playerColor").html("<h2>" + data + "</h2>");
}
```

Comment: I already have a getter/setter for playerColor and already have type="json".
i've put data instead of playerColor in html but still same issue

Comment: what about `result` tag in `struts.xml`. @AymaneELJahrani

Comment: I tried to put playerColor instead of my link : it didn't work

Comment: After all changes application was reloaded or not.

Comment: of course i did reload everything.
I'll try to clean everything again and try just to be sure

Comment: If application was reloaded and even though its not working after changes done means you have some other issue.

Comment: So you are sure from the method? If yes thank you a lot i'll try to find what's wrong

Comment: I'm sure in that if getter of `playerColor` is `public` and changes had did as above means it should work. try to post getters/setters too.

Comment: I tried everything and still nothing .
Actually when i put only sucess on ajax call ,  i get the page content displayed twice but the data are still not loaded.
When i add url :"gotoGameAction" i get the weird "Object Object" displayed

Comment: Does it action method executed or not just check put some logger or sysout for this and also prompt response `data` in `alert`.

Comment: I ran this in debug mode :
when i don't put url : gotoGameAction in ajax call the method execute in GameAction is never called

Answer (score 0):

You might not understand what is a JSON result type and how the content is provided by the action which is executing this result type.

To get more about plugin and documentation see [JSON Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/).

You can also look in the source code for the class which is being executed the [JSONResult](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/plugins/json/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/json/JSONResult.java). Then you see that

> ```
> /**
>  * This result type doesn't have a default param, null is ok to reduce noise in logs
>  */
> public static final String DEFAULT_PARAM = null;
> ```

<sub>***However such noise sometimes is helpful if you are debugging the code.***</sub>

That makes no any sense in your code

```
<result name="success" type="json">/WEB-INF/views/game.jsp</result>
```

The you need to dig into the tutorial and examples how to use this result. One of them you can find [here](https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/).

Another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096564/573032) might help you to decide whether you need a json result or use any other result suitable for JSON response.

Combining all that together will make an idea to rewrite your code to get it working.

Comment: None of you have helped me i resolved this mysefl by using $.getJSON instead of a classic get request using $.ajax. However thank you :)

Comment: `getJson`  is the same like ajax having set properties by default values.